# Discord.js Embed Buttons v12

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I just wanted to make a embed with 2 buttons but it doesn't seem what i want

```
 if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("?bhelp")) {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Hello ${message.author.username}!`)
      .setDescription("Prefix for this server is `?b`")
      .setColor("ORANGE")
      .addField("️ | Utlity", "`help` `whoareyou` `ping` `offserver` `updates` `timer` `ticket`")
      .addField("️ | Moderation", "`bgevents` `clear` `mute` `warn` `unmute` `serverinfo` `info` `ban` `userinfo` `slowmode` `poll` `eval` `membercount` `create-channel` `delete-channel` `lock` `unlock` `unban` `giverole` `removerole`")
      .addField(" | Image Genration", "`cmm` `slap` `meme`")
      .addField(":smile: Fun", "`avatar` `kill` `thanks` `nitro` `hug` `chatbot` `8ball` `noobrate` `dice` `nuke` `jumble` `weather` `rps` `search`")
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter(`GREETINGS ${message.author.username}:D`)
      let but = new disbut.MessageButton()
      .setStyle('url')
      .setLabel('Invite me!')
      .setURL('https://dsc.gg/blab')
      let but1 = new disbut.MessageButton()
      .setStyle('url')
      .setLabel('Vote me on Top.gg!')
      .setURL('https://top.gg/bot/885379319122264075')
    message.channel.send(embed).then(m =>{m.channel.send(but,but1)})
  }
```

heres the code but here what output i see

[Picture of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEwT1.png)

can anybody help me?

Comment: Is this v12? Update to v13 since buttons are already there

Comment: but i am learning v12 since my v12 is favorite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be sending any text or embeds like this

```js
message.channel.send(embed).then(m =>{m.channel.send(but,but1)})
```

You should remember to only send one string of text or one embed/button at a time. The fixed version would look like this

```js
message.channel.send(embed).then(m => {
    m.channel.send(but)
    m.channel.send(but1)
})
```

Comment: THX FOR HELP :3 UWU